# Someone risks accepting/to accept

Tags: grammar

1. Someone risks accepting inappropriate materials.
2. Someone risks to accept inappropriate materials.

How these sentences differ meaningwise?

Comment: I edited the OP from A risks to Someone risks

Answer (score 5):

These would be acceptable sentences:

> - Someone risks accepting inappropriate materials.
> - It is a risk to accept inappropriate materials.

Note that I changed the verb in the second sentence to the noun *a risk*. The construction with the noun can be followed by a to-infinitive while the verb cannot.

About the difference in meaning:

- The first sentence is stating a **possibility**. The person *someone* (in this case unknown, but the sentence works just as fine if you replace it with *My father* for example) **might accept** inappropriate materials.
- In the second sentence you're talking about a **condition**:

  - **If** you *accept inappropriate materials*, you're taking a risk.
  - **By** *accepting inappropriate emails*, you take a risk.

Your second sentence, where you used *risk + to-infinitive* is not grammatical.
If you take a look at the verb *risk* here (scroll down a little for the verb) in [the Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/risk), you will see that it is followed by an *ing-form* of the verb you're using it with.

*Risk* is one of those verbs that can be followed by an ing-form, but not an infinitve. Some verbs can be followed by both, with or without a difference in meaning. Others can only be used with a to-infinitive, a bare infinitive or an ing-form, but not all three of those forms.

There are not really any rules for this, you just have to learn them by heart or make a guess when you're using a verb. Practice makes perfect.

On the Cambridge Dictionary website, you can also find [a list of verb patterns](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing). I suggest you take a look at that page if you would like to learn more about this specific subject.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of following a noun, but not a verb,  with an infinitive.

Comment: +1 but I'd also add a comment about the "difference in meaning" to directly answer the question

Comment: I added the difference in meaning. Please have a look and tell me whether or not you agree.

Answer (score 0):

Risk should agree in number with the singular article, a. Otherwise, the sentences have no difference in meaning. You're taking a risk accepting inappropriate materials. The word *taking* is a participle. It's a risk to accept inappropriate materials. The word pair *to accept* is an infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

> Someoane risks accepting inappropriate materials.

would be the [acceptable version](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_list.htm).

Using the infinitive may not be grammatical.

Comment: Why part would be helpful.

Comment: The link explains that some verbs can be followed by a gerund, some by an infinitive, and others by either.  The why is that it's English.

Comment: @AST Pace, Thank you for your comment. Evidently I trust you, as a native, and not that wrong table that has the title: "Verbs followed by Gerunds". Yet, there are the following specifications:  9= verb followed by a gerund OR a noun + an infinitive
13 = verb followed by a gerund OR an infinitive with a difference in meaning
14 = verb followed by a gerund OR an infinitive with little difference in meaning
As you can see *risk* contains neither 9 nor 13 nor 14. Thence we conclude it is followed *only* by gerund which is misleading.

Comment: Misleading is [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Risks+to+accept%2C+risks+accepting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crisks%20accepting%3B%2Cc0) too, as Ngrams not found: Risks to accept

Comment: @JoeKim, no, it is a wrong site, that source is unreliable.

Comment: @ASTPace, there's another table on that site containing verbs followed by infinitives.

Comment: My comment was written in support of your answer.  As I read Ngrams, it also supports your answer. The table of verbs followed by infinitives supports your answer. Your comments sound like you disagree with your own answer.